# In Android Studio, I could see only simple form of "Create New Class" Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class

I'm using Android Studio 4.2.2 in MAC OS.

When I added Class with "New --> Java Class", I could see only Simple form of Dialog.
[image]
However, I checked android developer. I could see kind of full option dialog. How can I see this full option dialog?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Full Option Dialog" that you are talking about was available in older versions of Android Studio. If that's all you want to have then install an older version. The "Full Option Dialog" doesn't do anything more than adding a couple of more lines during the class creation. That's it.

Comment: Are you saying the options in the old dialog are completely useless?  If not, how can we add those lines?

Comment: Yes, that is quite true. The old dialog contained a bunch of options which made creating new files a bit difficult. Now it is much simpler and provides way cleaner look in my opinion.

Comment: @YanKingYin Your statement is a bit unclear to me, but from what I understand. Adding "those lines" isn't a big thing. It's just basic java. Eg: Whether you want your class to be private or public, which java class it would extend... and things along those lines. It shouldn't be too difficult to write a few words after file creation I assume.